# Como percorrer corretamente todos os itens de um checkedListBox C#?

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um checkedListBox num tabControl do form. No checkedlListBox há vários itens que podem ser selecionados.

Quando o usuário clica no botão abaixo do checkedListBox, é lançado um loop que verifica se teve itens selecionados ou não, caso teve, o usuário é redirecionado para uma outra tabPage.

Caso não selecionou nenhuma opção, aparece a MessageBox. Mas o grande problema é que isso apenas para o primeiro item do checkedListBox.

Caso seja selecionado o segundo ou o terceiro e etc, aparece o MessageBox como se o usuário não tivesse selecionado nada.

Então, retomando ao título: como percorrer todos os itens de um checkedListBox?

Código que está funcionando com o primeiro item:

```
    private void btnEditarValores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (ListBoxSAdicionais.Items.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            if (ListBoxSAdicionais.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(dados3);
                this.tabControl1.SelectTab(2);
                break;
            }
            else if ((ListBoxSAdicionais.GetItemChecked(i) == false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Você deve selecionar algum Status Adicional para editar os valores.");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: não seria o break dentro do if o problema?

Comment: Quando o usuário é redirecionado pra tabPage(dados3) não deve aparecer o MessageBox do outro if e se eu tirar o break do primeiro if, ele fica aparecendo. Se eu tirar o break do else if, vai ficar mandando MessageBox até o loop percorrer a quantidade de items do checkedListBox. Já tentei remover a alternar os breaks, não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você primeiramente pode usar o método [`CheckedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) que irá retornar se existem ou não itens selecionados. Caso o `Count` seja zero, você mostra a mensagem, senão você faz a troca da aba

```
private void btnEditarValores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBoxSAdicionais.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Você deve selecionar algum Status Adicional para editar os valores.");
    else
    {
        this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(dados3);
        this.tabControl1.SelectTab(2);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Era isso... Bom, como eu não pensei nisso? haha.C# é minha primeira linguagem de programação e estou tentando fazer o famoso "learn by doing". Muito obrigado ;)

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que vc não está verificando todos os itens pois seu "for" para na primeira tentativa, pois cai no "if" ou "else if";

Sugestão:

```
bool isChecked = false;

private void btnEditarValores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(CheckBox item in ListBoxSAdicionais.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsChecked == true)
        {
            isChecked = true;

            break;
        }
    }

    if(isChecked == true)
    {
         this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(dados3);
        this.tabControl1.SelectTab(2);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Você deve selecionar algum Status Adicional para editar os valores.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu entendi o código e, inclusive, irei usá-lo para outra coisa, pois este problema atual já resolvi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Só pra deixar claro, o meu comentário era pra pergunta e não pra sua resposta (que está certa). Eu me confundi e comentei no lugar errado. E, embora este `isChecked == true` me incomode, não fui eu quem negativou =D

Comment: Concordo, a resposta do PabloVargas foi melhor. 

Nem vi que haviam negativado. Sempre há alguns downvotes perambulando pelo site. hahaha

Mas me fala sobre o isChecked, irei melhorar minha lógica.

Answer (score 1):

E assim ficou meu código no final de tudo: (Foi adicionado else if para não dar Unreachable code detected, pois se retirar alguns dos break vai ficar repetindo o MessageBox em algum local)

```
    public void btnEditarValores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (ListBoxSAdicionais.Items.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            if (ListBoxSAdicionais.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Você deve selecionar algum Status Adicional para editar os valores.");
                break;
            }
            else if (ListBoxSAdicionais.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(dados3);
                this.tabControl1.SelectTab(2);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wevelly Felipe, você não precisa do for e nem dos break.

Comment: Editei minha resposta com o evento click do botão

Comment: Outro detalhe, você não precisa responder mostrando como ficou seu código, basta somente aceitar minha resposta como correta.

Comment: Ah ok, obrigado mais uma vez ^^.